# Issue while using Bootstrap and LESS in React project configured with Webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-4, less

Please refer my files for this project.

The issue that I am facing is that when I apply some **custom css (LESS file)** to any element what happens is that first my **bootstrap css** gets applied and after a fraction of second my custom css gets applied.

I am able to see the lag.

For example, first my `div` is 100% width and after a **lag** I see my custom width of `300px` getting applied.

**index.js**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  browserHistory,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import {
  HomePage,
  LoginPage,
  SignupPage,
  ForgotPasswordPage
} from './screens';

import {
  Provider
} from 'react-redux';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './style/main.less';

import configureStore from './store';
const store = configureStore();

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
              <Route exact path="/register" component={SignupPage} />
                <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPasswordPage} />
            </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/index.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.[name].[hash].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                  presets: ['react', 'env', 'stage-1']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                  }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader', options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                  }, {
                    loader: 'less-loader', options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
     },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    }
};
```

Simply writing my css in LESS files. Calling the main LESS file and bootstrap css in the `index.js`. Using classes on the div.

Comment: That is normal, your bootstrap.css gets loaded first, then it loads your less files which overrides everything else. You either create a copy of bootstrap yourself and delete everything that is conflicting, or live with that

Comment: Better use mini-css-extract plugin to be able to extract everything to files, then they get downloaded at the same time and applied at the same time